# Split string Based on bracket in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string EXTREME MAKEOVER (SEA VERSION) (YR 1 EPS 1-11) and I need to split it into separate string and store in array in Javascript.

in C# equivalent

```
splitBracket = str.Split(new string[] {"(",")"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Do you need to split based on brackets ??

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with some regex to split based on parentheses (and any surrounding whitespace), then filter out the (falsy) empty strings.

```js
const str = 'EXTREME MAKEOVER (SEA VERSION) (YR 1 EPS 1-11)';
const splitBracket = str.split(/\s*[\(\)]\s*/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(splitBracket);
```

Comment: Or `str.split(/[\(\)]/).map(item => item.trim()).filter(Boolean)` if you find that more readable.

Comment: Tried it out. Works as expected. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), together with the regular expression `/[\(\)]/` to achieve this:

```js
const input = 'EXTREME MAKEOVER (SEA VERSION) (YR 1 EPS 1-11)';
const result = input.split(/[\(\)]/)

console.log(result) // ["EXTREME MAKEOVER ", "SEA VERSION", " ", "YR 1 EPS 1-11", ""]
```